# Why integral "disappears" in differential form of Gauss's law?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am learning to apply the differential form of Gauss's law and found an article titled [Differential form of Gauss's law](http://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys263/wth/fall04/downloads/Gauss/divergence.pdf) to learn it from.

However, in the paragraph that explains equation (6) in the article, the author says "....,the integrals can be replaced by" and introduces a new expression without the integrals. Is it related to the fundamental theorem of calculus?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author is taking the limit as the volume of integration goes to zero. Any integral of a proper function (not distributions like Dirac deltas) over a zero-size region is zero.